# Gridview onclick in dialog modal with bootstrap in asp.net return values to modal father page webforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have spend all day trying and searching how to click in a row in a gridview inside a modal-popup and returns theses values to labels/textboxs on the "father" of the modal-popup, I'm already using javascript to open and closes the modal. The return can be placed in the closeModal(). I just need a example, I have looked in a lot of foruns and pages and didn't find one like this. Thank you for you help

Heres is the ASP.NET Code

```
<script>
    function openModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show')
    };

    function closeModal() {
        console.log("Sai")
        $('#myModal').modal('hide')
        document.getElementById('<%= lblTeste.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'Your new value';
        console.log("valor mudado")
    };

  function sendTex(texto) {
        document.getElementById('<%= txtExample.ClientID %>') = texto;
    }
</script>

<asp:Label id="lblSelected" runat="server"></asp:Label>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content" runat="server">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusca" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvBusca"  OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="id" 
                        runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" 
                        BorderStyle="None" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover ">
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnBusca" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                        <asp:Label id="lblValor" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </ContentTemplate>                       
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the behind code:

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvBusca.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvBusca, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        e.Row.Attributes("style") = "cursor:pointer"
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvBusca.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim index As Integer = gvBusca.SelectedRow.RowIndex
    Dim name As String = gvBusca.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text
    Dim country As String = gvBusca.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
    Dim message As String = "Row Index: " & index & "\nName: " & name + "\nCountry: " & country
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Desc", "sendText('" + name + "');", True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById('<%= txtExample.ClientID %>').value = texto;`

I think you forgot to add `.value` in the above statement.